# Model update on keydown for TextInput

Tags: ariatemplates

How can I make a TextInput widget update the model on keyup or keydown (like AutoComplete) instead of blur?

I saw in the sources that these events are added in DropDownTextInput, so I guess I didn't just miss a configuration option. Is creating a new widget mandatory to get the behavior I want? Is there an easier way? Or code snippets maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about the style provided by the default skin, you could simply use the @html:TextInput widget.

It provides a `type` event out of the box.

For the `TEMPLATE_ERROR` on instantAt, it's bug that should be fixed asap.

Comment: I had trouble finding the correct lib path and the widget configuration, so here it is: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5584653

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to achieve the desired behavior, but I'm really not satisfied with it. It makes no sense from a semantic perspective and it exploits another widget for something it's clearly not made for. But at least it very simple to do.

So, I just used an AutoComplete widget with a hacked resource handler. I update the model value in getSuggestion:

```
getHandler : function (args) {
    var handler = new aria.resources.handlers.LCResourcesHandler();
    handler.getSuggestions = function(textEntry, cb) {
        aria.utils.Json.setValue(args.inside, args.filterValue, textEntry);
        this.$callback(cb);
    }
    return handler
}
```

demo on [instantat](http://juliandescottes.github.io/instantat/#51934eb5e4b073bf167f3d66)

Somehow it fails when loading from the url. Put a space somewhere to refresh it and it will work.